# Pass variables to different processes using call activity in Camunda

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler, camunda-plugin, camunda-spin

How to pass data  from one Process to another in code  .I am using Spring Boot in Java code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a call activity, then you don't need code to start the referenced process and to pass data. The engine will take care of it if you model the corresponding attributes.

[image]

Also see documentation here: https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/modeler/bpmn/call-activities/

Comment: i dont see `Propogate all variables` option. I am using 4.7 version of modeler and camunda 7

Comment: On 4.x it is on the Input/Output tab and called a littler differently (copy all data or so). Recommend you upgrade to 5.x modeler. Current version is 5.7 and you can download it here: https://camunda.com/download/modeler/. This also works with Camunda 7

Comment: Will modeler 5.x work with Camunda 7`.i cantuse camunda 8

Comment: Yes, you can select in the start screen which kind of model you want to create

Comment: Thanks it working with 4.7 too.`Variable` tab and select `all`.

Comment: yes, sure. I would upgrade anyway. working with 5.x is much nicer